# Overload resolution ambiguity for higher order functions with a generic input

Tags: kotlin

I have the following two higher order functions in Kotlin:

```
operator fun <T1> ((T1) -> Double).plus(f1: (T1) -> Double): (T1) -> Double = { t1: T1 -> TODO() }

operator fun <T1, T2> ((T1) -> Double).plus(f2: (T2) -> Double): (T1, T2) -> Double = { t1: T1, t2: T2 -> TODO() }

object A

object B

fun test(a: (A) -> Double, b: (B) -> Double): (A, B) -> Double = a + b
```

On the last line, I receive the following error:

```
Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public operator fun <T1> ((TypeVariable(T1)) -> Double).plus(f1: (TypeVariable(T1)) -> Double): (TypeVariable(T1)) -> Double defined in root package
public operator fun <T1, T2> ((TypeVariable(T1)) -> Double).plus(f2: (TypeVariable(T2)) -> Double): (TypeVariable(T1), TypeVariable(T2)) -> Double defined in root package
```

When the last line is removed, this code compiles without any errors. If these two functions truly cannot be disambiguated, I would expect the function declarations themselves to clash (e.g. "Conflicting overloads"). If they are valid declarations, how can I invoke these functions unambiguously?

Comment: What's your Kotlin compiler version? I'm not having described issue with Kotlin 1.2.61

Comment: I am using the most recent version, `1.3.50`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you have two kinds of unusual operator overloads. The problem is that the compiler cannot know which one should be used. What if you would like to call the second operator with the same types? The type cannot be deduced.

What you can do? All infix functions can be invoked in the "normal" way. And then you can specify what method exactly you want to use, as the compiler cannot be sure in that call:

```
fun test(a: (A) -> Double, b: (B) -> Double): (A, B) -> Double = a.plus<A, B>(b)
fun test(a: (A) -> Double, b: (A) -> Double): (A) -> Double = a.plus<A>(b)
```

**A deep dive:**

Everything seems to be OK, because the compiler should be smart enough to detect the type. But...

Lambdas are represented in the JVM as `kotlin.jvm.functions.Function*` (where * is number of arguments). And generic type is erased. If so, let's decompile the generated code:

```
public final class OverloadKt {
   @NotNull
   public static final Function1 plus(@NotNull Function1 $this$plus, @NotNull Function1 f1) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull($this$plus, "$this$plus");
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(f1, "f1");
      return (Function1)null.INSTANCE;
   }

   @NotNull
   public static final Function2 plus(@NotNull Function1 $this$plus, @NotNull Function1 f2) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull($this$plus, "$this$plus");
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(f2, "f2");
      return (Function2)null.INSTANCE;
   }
}
```

There is no difference between they definitions!
What is interesting, let's add a main method that will execute those methods:

```
fun main() {
    val aLambda = { a: A -> 10.0 }
    val bLambda = { b: B -> 20.0 }

    aLambda.plus<A, B>(bLambda)
    aLambda.plus<A>(aLambda)
}
```

And the decompiled code:

```
public final class OverloadKt {

   public static final void main() {
      Function1 aLambda = (Function1)null.INSTANCE;
      Function1 bLambda = (Function1)null.INSTANCE;
      plus(aLambda, bLambda);
      plus(aLambda, aLambda);
   }

   // $FF: synthetic method
   public static void main(String[] var0) {
      main();
   }
}
```

If we would print result of those two operators we would get:

```
(T1, T2) -> kotlin.Double
(T1) -> kotlin.Double
```

So, from the decompiled code it's hard to say why the compiler knows what call should be done, but the proper operator is called!

But Kotlin adds something more to its files - metadata.

```
@Metadata(
   mv = {1, 1, 15},
   bv = {1, 0, 3},
   k = 2,
   d1 = {"..."},
   d2 = {"main", "", "plus", "Lkotlin/Function1;", "T1", "", "f1", "Lkotlin/Function2;", "T2", "f2", "sandbox"}
)
```

Let's see the bytecode calls for the main method:

```
  // access flags 0x19
  public final static main()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 10 L0
    GETSTATIC OverloadKt$main$aLambda$1.INSTANCE : LOverloadKt$main$aLambda$1;
    CHECKCAST kotlin/jvm/functions/Function1
    ASTORE 0
   L1
    LINENUMBER 11 L1
    GETSTATIC OverloadKt$main$bLambda$1.INSTANCE : LOverloadKt$main$bLambda$1;
    CHECKCAST kotlin/jvm/functions/Function1
    ASTORE 1
   L2
    LINENUMBER 13 L2
    ALOAD 0
    ALOAD 1
    INVOKESTATIC OverloadKt.plus (Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1;)Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function2;
    POP
   L3
    LINENUMBER 14 L3
    ALOAD 0
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESTATIC OverloadKt.plus (Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1;)Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1;
    POP
   L4
    LINENUMBER 15 L4
    RETURN
   L5
    LOCALVARIABLE bLambda Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1; L2 L5 1
    LOCALVARIABLE aLambda Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1; L1 L5 0
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 2
```

So, from the generated bytecode it's clear how the compiler deduces which method should be called. That's all. :D

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this is a great explanation! I guess the takeaway message is that by looking at the call site, it is not possible to disambiguate two higher order infix functions with different generic type signatures, due to type erasure in the JVM. Sadly, it is not possible to disambiguate them using the `@JvmName` annotation either, which usually works for functions with conflicting JVM signatures, but not in this case for some reason. I was hoping there might have been a workaround using the `inline` and `reified` keywords, but alas this does not seem to be possible in Kotlin.